# How to set up Azure Application Gateway with multiple App Services that also talk to each other

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I want to protect a number of Azure App Services with Web Application Firewall.
I was able to make it work with one app and on the way to adding the other apps.

Is there any recommended way or things to consider given the fact that some of these apps talk to each other?
If AppA queries AppB, I understand that the call would not be routed through the internet since it's all between azure IPs, is that right?
But would that skip the Application Gateway?